# Git bad merges: understanding them

Tags: git, merge, conflict, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a quick question that I was hoping someone could explain or at least point me to some documentation. I have read the git-merge man page but I still don't understand what makes this happen.

Our master branch is version 1.

A couple of our developers and a graphics designer have been working on their own branches of master for about three weeks. The developers have been making patches and updates. The graphics designer has been working on a version 2 - a complete redesign.

I've been scared of merging this as I have seen git make bad merges before, essentially overwriting code and breaking stuff.

Anyway, we had a lot of merge conflicts, and sure enough halfway through the second file I spot something that that does not seems right. I call the designer and developer together and sure enough, the designers changes were overwritten.

Now, the developer has never checked out a copy of the designers work nor merged it into their branch. It is possible however that the designer at some point checked out the master branch and resolved some conflicts on their own to get some of the latest changes ( I don't know if this matters or not, but I would expect in this case that the designers commits would have overwritten the developers).

As mentioned, this is not the first time that something like this has happened and as this is a pretty big merge, I'd like to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into a more sophisticated workflow for your team. For me, the goal is to keep master as a log of purely working commits and use feature/hotfix branches to work on. This is based off the [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model.

As an example, suppose you're a developer working on user authentication. You would:

- Check out a new branch from develop: `git checkout -b feature/auth develop`
- Make some changes
- Commit your code: `git commit -m 'commit message'`

Now you want to push your changes to develop. Unfortunately, a designer has pushed some changes, one of which affects a file in your commit. This means your branch has 'diverged' from develop.

- Run `git rebase develop` to overlay the changes to develop onto your feature commits
- If there are conflicts, you'll need to fix them
- Once conflicts are resolved, continue the rebase.

Once you're ready, you can push the tip of `develop` to `master`. Check out the link I posted above for more information on release branches, hotfixes, etc.